# How do I use json instead of plist to populate TableView

Tags: json, uitableview, swift2, plist

I have a working App which takes data from a pList on a remote server. However, I now want to use json instead of plist and am struggling with understanding how to do this! Any help much appreciated and any examples awesome.

Some selected code - first download of plist and second populating the TableView using the downloaded plist. Note: I have not included ALL the code.

```
@IBAction func startDownload(sender: AnyObject) {
progressView.hidden = false

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://ftp.iphoneData@dittodata.host-ed.me/Annotations/myAnnotationsKalkan.plist")!
    downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url)
    downloadTask.resume()
}

func showFileWithPath(path: String){
    let isFileFound:Bool? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
    if isFileFound == true{
        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        viewer.delegate = self
        viewer.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
       // print("file is found")
    }
}

@IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// 1
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
    didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let destinationURLForFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString("/myAnnotationsKalkan.plist.plist"))

    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationURLForFile.path!){
        showFileWithPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
    }
    else{
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURLForFile)
//             show file
            showFileWithPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }
}

// 2
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
                didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                             totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                             totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){
    progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite), animated: true)
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                task: NSURLSessionTask,
                didCompleteWithError error: NSError?){
    downloadTask = nil
    progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)

    if (error != nil) {
        print(error?.description)
    }else{
      //  print("The task finished transferring data successfully")
         progressView.hidden = true
    }
}


//  TableViewController.swift
    /  museumTemplate

//

import UIKit


class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var titleData = [String]()
var subTitleData = [String]()
var stateData = [String]()
var codeData = [String]()
var infoData = [String]()
var openData = [String]()
var phoneData = [String]()
var emailData = [String]()
var webData = [String]()
var latData = [Double]()
var lonData = [Double]()

var titleToPass = [String]()
var thisState = [String]()
var stateOrAlpha = ""
var titleText = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

navigationItem.title = titleText

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let sourcePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myAnnotationsKalkan.plist.plist")

    if let content = NSArray(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String){


    let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: stateOrAlpha, ascending: true)
    let myMuseum = content.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])

        for item in myMuseum{
                titleData.append(item.objectForKey("title") as! String)
                subTitleData.append(item.objectForKey("subtitle") as! String)
                infoData.append(item.objectForKey("info") as! String)
                phoneData.append(item.objectForKey("phone") as! String)
                webData.append(item.objectForKey("web") as! String)
                emailData.append(item.objectForKey("email") as! String)
                latData.append(item.objectForKey("latitude") as! Double)
                lonData.append(item.objectForKey("longitude") as! Double)
            }
        }
    }

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return titleData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell..title and subTitle.
   cell.textLabel!.text = titleData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: It's pretty bad programming habit to use 13(!) arrays as data source. Swift is an object oriented language, so use a custom class or struct. Unlike property list a JSON file is plain text. You can use `dataTask` rather than `downloadTask` and you have to convert (deserialize) the text to an array or dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and info

Comment: I should have added that I do use a custom class in similar code in other Apps. This one I am experimenting and is quick and dirty :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code for downloading a simple json file from a server and it seems to work:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://ftp.iphoneData@dittodata.host-ed.me/Annotations/testData4.json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
    let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("File downloaded.")
   //         print(testData4.json)
            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                if let users = json["users"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for user in users {
                        if let name = user["name"] as? String {
                        if let subtitle = user["subtitle"] as? String {
                        print(name,subtitle)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i use Alamofire wich is more easier and safe to do Web requests, but here is a code without it:

```
 let urlPath = "YourUrlRequest"
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if let  responseData = data {
                do {
                    let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as! NSArray
                    for dataDict : AnyObject in jsonObject {

                        let idj: String = dataDict.objectForKey("id") as!String
                        let namej: String = dataDict.objectForKey("name") as! String
                        let indicativej: String = dataDict.objectForKey("indicative") as! String
                        let flagj: String = dataDict.objectForKey("flag") as! String
                        saveCountryFromWeb(idj, name: namej, indicative: indicativej, flag: flagj)

                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                }

            }.resume()
```

Hope the helps, tell me in case you want a sample with alamofire which i recommend ;)

Comment: Kika_Fortez Have not used Alamofire, so yes please re: a sample. Although my intention is to use Firebase for data access when I sort things out. Thank you for your positive help

Comment: ok, so to retrieve data with firebase you don't need to use them because firebase has his methods by default so i will put a firebase example. Please put a check as the right answer.

Comment: Finally found some time to play with your code. Am getting a error with this line

let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as! NSArray

SIGABRT - Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x44c5c0) to 'NSArray' (0x44c2f0).

Comment: ok! try to instead, this code:  let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

Comment: Thank you. However, I had already tried that and brings up the error 'key:AnyObject, value:AnyObject)' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

I did, however, get some working code (any comments/improvements welcome). Next, when time allows, I will try to implement the sample you provided for Firebase :-) Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

```
func retrieveBarcodeData(){

    let databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseref.child("barcodes").queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        snapshot in


        let codig = snapshot.value!["codigo"] as! String
        let desc = snapshot.value!["designacao"] as! String
        let Url = snapshot.value!["ImageURL"] as! String

        barcodes.insert(BarCodeStruct(code: codig, description: desc, ImageURL: Url),atIndex: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()



    })

}
```

Don't forget to configure your database in firebase, and install firebase with cocoapods and put FIRApp.configure() in your appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions